# Expanding quad to be oriented along control points

Tags: canvas, rotation, trigonometry, rotational-matrices

I have a problem with expanding and orienting a 4 vertices quad along two control points. I made this picture to illustrate my problem:

[image]

Here is my HTML5 canvas code trying to solve this problem. Assume I have array of `{ x: number, y: number }` for each 2D position:

Here is a full code snippet:

```js
console.clear()

const c = document.createElement('canvas')
const ctx = c.getContext("2d")

c.width = innerWidth
c.height = innerHeight
document.body.appendChild(c)

ctx.fillStyle = "black"
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height)

ctx.fillStyle = "red"
ctx.strokeStyle = "white"

const offset = 10

const points = []
const pointsNum = 10
const spacingX = 800 / pointsNum

const positions = []
for (let i = 0; i < pointsNum + 1; i++) {
  const x = i * spacingX + 100
  const y = (Math.random() * 2 - 1) * 100 + 200
  positions.push({x, y})
}

for (let i = 0; i < pointsNum; i++) {
  const { x: currX, y: currY } = positions[i]
  const { x: nextX, y: nextY } = positions[i + 1]
  
  const dx = nextX - currX
  const dy = nextY - currY
  const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx)
  
  const x1 = currX - offset
  const y1 = currY - offset
  const x2 = currX - offset
  const y2 = currY + offset
  
  const x3 = nextX + offset
  const y3 = nextY + offset
  const x4 = nextX + offset
  const y4 = nextY - offset
  
  ctx.fillRect(currX - 3, currY - 3, 6, 6)
  
  ctx.moveTo(x1, y1)
  ctx.lineTo(x2, y2)
  ctx.lineTo(x3, y3)
  ctx.lineTo(x4, y4)
  ctx.closePath()
  ctx.stroke()
}
```

As you can see I am stuck at step 3. I understand some kind of rotation needs to be applied to each quad vertex to orient it (notice I already calculate `angle`), but can't work out what exactly needs to happen.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If we look at your control point **P1** and it's four surrounding vertices - without any rotation applied yet - we can see that the vertices **are** at specific angles yet.
[image]

Since in Javascript an angle of 0° is at the 3 'o clock position and increases clockwise, we can say that:

- V1==-135°
- V2==-45°
- V3==45°
- V4==135°

In an [unit-circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle), given an angle we can calculate any point on it's circumference by computing the sine and it's cosine. If we then multiply the result by a number (`offset` in your case) and add the origin of **P1** we know exactly where to draw this point on screen.

In your case though the quad described by the four vertices can be rotated - which does not make things any more complicated. All you have to do is adding the rotation to the vertex initial angle.

So say we want to draw **V1** and the quad is rotated by 22° it's actual rotation is -113°.

Here's an example:

```js
const c = document.createElement('canvas')
const ctx = c.getContext("2d")

c.width = innerWidth
c.height = innerHeight
document.body.appendChild(c)

ctx.fillStyle = "black"
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height)

ctx.fillStyle = "red"
ctx.strokeStyle = "white"

const offset = 10

const points = []
const pointsNum = 10
const spacingX = 800 / pointsNum

const positions = []
for (let i = 0; i < pointsNum + 1; i++) {
    const x = i * spacingX + 100
    const y = (Math.random() * 2 - 1) * 100 + 200
    positions.push({
        x,
        y
    })
}

for (let i = 0; i < pointsNum; i++) {
    const {
        x: currX,
        y: currY
    } = positions[i]
    const {
        x: nextX,
        y: nextY
    } = positions[i + 1]

    const dx = nextX - currX
    const dy = nextY - currY
    const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx)

    const x1 = currX + Math.cos(-135 * (Math.PI / 180) + angle) * offset;
    const y1 = currY + Math.sin(-135 * (Math.PI / 180) + angle) * offset;
    const x2 = currX + Math.cos(135 * (Math.PI / 180) + angle) * offset;
    const y2 = currY + Math.sin(135 * (Math.PI / 180) + angle) * offset;

    const x3 = nextX + Math.cos(-45 * (Math.PI / 180) + angle) * offset;
    const y3 = nextY + Math.sin(-45 * (Math.PI / 180) + angle) * offset;
    const x4 = nextX + Math.cos(45 * (Math.PI / 180) + angle) * offset;
    const y4 = nextY + Math.sin(45 * (Math.PI / 180) + angle) * offset;

    ctx.fillRect(currX - 3, currY - 3, 6, 6);
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1)
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2)
    ctx.lineTo(x4, y4)
    ctx.lineTo(x3, y3)
    ctx.closePath()
    ctx.stroke()
}
```